# How to show driving route in ios maps

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How can i show driving route in ios map. Currenly i have shown only a route from starting point to destination. In android google map provides it by default, is there any way in iphone to redirect to ios map with starting point and destination. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997388/ios-driving-directions-in-ios6

Comment: Have you searched in google ..?

Comment: yes,not get any proper method

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 you can do it easily without transferring user from your app to map app. Please check the [Link](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-7-tutorial-series-map-kit) and provide your response.

It says

> **MKDirectionRequest and MKDirectionResponse**
>
> Many mobile users rely on directions from their device and in iOS 7 developers can now provide them within the context of your app instead of switching to the Maps application. You start your request with a source and destination. Other options include alternate routes, transport type and time of departure/arrival.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can accept it as a solution for answer if you are agreed with it

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to customize much such as pins and popup. You can add UIWebview to the ViewController and and along with the webURL for Google maps append the From and To locations and then load it.
else
You have to add Googlemaps and have to do draw polygon routes yourself using methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mainHelper currentLocation].coordinate;

MKPlacemark* placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem* destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];
if([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:)])
{
    //using iOS6 native maps app
    if(dirType == WALK)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking}];

    }
    if(dirType == DRIVE)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

    }
    if(dirType == TRANSIT)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

    }

}
```