# Options for displaying multiple routes on iPhone Map (iOS 4+)

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, routes, apple-maps

I am trying to develop an iPhone app (with map routing function), and I need everyone's suggestions (guidance).

Below are a few specs:

1. The app will be running on iPhone with iOS 4+.
2. The app will have Map functionality.
3. In the app, given a "few locations" in a given order (to make things less complicated), the Map will draw routes between each locations on the Map.
4. Clicking on any location will display another page that shows some information about that location.
5. Can choose alternative route between two location (which I don't think is possible, but let me know if anyone know any framework that can do this).

I did some research, using Map on iPhone is easy using MapKit (and it's available after iOS 3.0). I followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial, and everything seems easy. However, if I want to draw routes on my map, I will need routes data in a CSV format. However, I do not have those data (yes! I suck).

And prior to iOS 5.1, MapKit use Google Maps, and I read somewhere that in Google Map's term and condition of use, it prohibit people from drawing on the Map (correct me if I am wrong).

In order to retrieve route data, I would imagine that I will have to get it through Google or Apple (I don't know if it's possible). I'm just wondering if Apple Map or Google Map have API to retrieve these?

If not, an alternative I came up with is to use a webview, and display my Map routes on Google Map. I'm just wondering if Google Map API will allow me to insert multiple locations and display all the routes?

I really need some suggestions... I am getting buried in all these problems.... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048) - MKOverlay is the way to go. One more [example is here](http://iosguy.com/tag/mkoverlayview/).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I am trying to find the route from location A to location B, and plot that route. Not from a user tracked route. Is there any way I can find out those route data?

Comment: The first link discusses drawing - the second link discusses where each route line should be drawn.

Comment: In other words, you need to send request to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ api,process the response and then implement drawing, just like you would as if you got it from a csv.

Comment: The tech side seems perfect. However, Google API terms and condition of use stated those data should only be displayed on Google Map, does that mean I am not allow to display it on Apple Map? would this stop Apple from passing my app inspection?

Comment: Not really sure. It's quite surprising that iOS6 relies on very crude way of opening maps app via URL or a mapitem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636707/how-can-i-get-direction-on-an-iphone-ios-6-app-in-xcode-from-a-to-b?lq=1.

Comment: On the other hand there are third parties like this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-ios-sdk/samples/index.htm

Comment: @NiravBhatt i've never used map..and i requirement is to display route of two points along with possible best alternative routes. plz suggest me. i read ur sample code. but not able to get